# FileNotFoundError at /main/insert_phone/

Tags: python, file

I am building a django app which sends texts using twilio. I'm trying to have it get the body of the message from a text file which is in the same directory as my views.py file, which is where the code for sending the text is. I'm getting this error: "FileNotFoundError at /main/insert_phone/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'textgenrnn_texts.txt'" and I'm not sure why because the name of the file is correct.

Here is the part of the views file where the issue is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# import pymsgbox
from .models import Phone
from .forms import Post
import subprocess

from twilio.rest import Client

...

def insert_phone_item(request: HttpRequest):
    phone = Phone(content=request.POST['content'])
    try:
        phone.full_clean()

    except ValidationError:
        return redirect('/main/list/')

    phone.save()

    # get receiver from postgres db
    reciever = Phone.objects.values_list('content', flat=True).distinct()

    # get text body from file
    with open('textgenrnn_texts.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read()

    client.messages.create(to=reciever, from_=sender, body=text)
    return redirect('/main/list/')
```

Comment: what's the full path to `textgenrnn_texts.txt`? if it isn't in the directory where you're running your program you need to give a full path to it.

Comment: @Macattack oh shoot so if it isn't in the directory of manage.py then it needs the full path, even though it's in the same directory of the views?

Comment: @Macattack changed the path and it worked! thanks!